# MySQL Select latest 1 row for each ID in table

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called sw_practice populated with organisations, and a second table called sw_invoices with the invoice data for each organisation.

Within sw_invoices, there could be several invoices (there is an incremental unique ID column) linked to the organisations with their own ID (Prac_ID).

I am trying to get a list of all organisations (whether they've been invoiced or not) but only 1 entry per organisation, so if they HAVE been invoiced, only the latest shows.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM sw_practices as p LEFT JOIN sw_invoices as i ON p.Prac_ID = i.Prac_ID WHERE p.Active = '2' ORDER BY i.Inv_ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

but this only shows the latest row out of them all.

And if I remove LIMIT 1 from the end it does show all of the data but shows more than 1 entry for some organisations.

I'd like the query to say "select all from sw_practices WHERE Active = 2 and show their invoice data but only show the latest 1 for each different Prac_ID"

Comment: This problem has been answered many times on Stack Overflow. See questions with the tag [tag:greatest-n-per-group].

Comment: Thanks Bill, I searched a few things before posting but couldn't see anything as similar as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group by:

```
SELECT * FROM sw_practices as p LEFT JOIN (Select * FROM sw_invoices ORDER BY Prac_ID DESC )as i ON p.Prac_ID = i.Prac_ID WHERE p.Active = '2' GROUP BY p.Prac_id
```

Comment: I spoke a bit too soon, it does only list 1 per practice which is exactly what I want but doesn't show the latest 1, it seems to be showing the earliest (first) one.

Comment: OK that one now shows all organisation data but no invoice data

Comment: select * in the sub query will do

Comment: That brought the invoice data back but still showing the first entry, not the latest.

Comment: I've got it now, changed Prac_ID in the sub-query to Inv_ID which is the unique ID for the rows of invoices (may have been some confusion from my novice explanation of things) and this has now changed each organisations invoice 01 to their most recent. Thanks again for your time with this, appreciated.